# Question about acute accentuation / l'accent aigu (é)

Tags: orthographe

Can anybody explain me this rule,

[image]

However when I decouple this word I obtain the following,

[image]

For me would've made sense, if *mélangé* had been disaggregated as: *mél-an-gé*; making the first syllable enclosed by two consonants.

**I am going also to accept answers completely written in French.**

Comment: What makes you think it depends on how you cut it down into syllables? Because it doesn't.  The first **é** in *mélangé* is indeed between tow consonants . You got that rule on [this page](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/articles/le-guide-de-usage-des-accents-en-francais) I expect. Can you please give the reference of your sources (or link to) whenever possible.

Comment: @None Because of what it seems to me an incongruence I am gently asking you an explanation. Yes, it is exactly that page, I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comme déjà dit en commentaire par None, la règle est correcte.

« Placée entre deux consonnes » ne signifie pas autre chose, le découpage syllabique n'intervient pas ici.

Comment: D'après la règle indiquée, **demander** devrait s'écrire ***démander** ? Ou alors il y a quelque chose que je n'ai pas compris...

Comment: @XouDo La deuxième proposition: Il y a quelque chose que tu n'as pas compris :-)  Cette règle et les autres de la même source traitent de la présence ou non d'un accent graphique (un diacritique) sur la lettre *E* lorsqu'elle est prononcée /e/. Avec *demander* ( \də.mɑ̃.de\ ), le premier *E* est prononcé [ə], voire pas du tout, donc la question de la présence d'un accent ne se pose pas. Le deuxième *E* est prononcé [e] mais l'accent graphique n'est pas représenté car ce *E* précède un *R* final (une autre règle décrite ailleurs).

Comment: Effectivement, Ce n'était pas précisé dans la question, mais c'est plus logique comme ça.