# Why is this verb contradicting this accentuation rule / accent aigu é?

Tags: orthographe

What is the explanation for this verb not following this rule [Rule's page](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/articles/le-guide-de-usage-des-accents-en-francais)?

[image]

[image]

What is the most appropriate rule to explain this?

[image]

I don't know whether I must take this page very seriously because of how *différencié* is written.

[image]

Comment: "What is the most appropriate rule to explain this?" It gives you the rule....it is stating the rule. //Re règle 4: **différencie** is the third person singular of the verb **différencier**;  to differentiate; differenci**é** is differentiate**d**, past participle. So the rule's grammar is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "*règle 6*" is incorrectly stated.

It only applies with word **ending** with *-ed*, *-ef*, *-er* and *-ez*.

Actually, outside abbreviations like *tél.* or *déc.*, *E* never has a acute accent when it is followed by a final consonant that is not an *S*, but only *D*, *F*, *R* and *Z* give it an accented pronunciation, the reason why these letters are listed in the rule (correction: the word *tel* has no written accent but is pronounced with an accented *E*).

*Différencie* is correctly written, it's the third person singular indicative, not a past participle.

Comment: Monosyllables and polysyllables?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: Could you point me out a page for learning accentuation rules?

Comment: I don't know any. The only rule that is taught at school, or at least, the only one I'm aware of, is that there should be no accent on *E* before a double consonant or an *X*.

Comment: @SNR Perhaps not precisely what you are looking for but the answer to that question [When to put an accent on the letter E](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1345/358) might help you.

Comment: @None It is certainly helpful and I appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find the answer in your other post :

[Question about acute accentuation / l'accent aigu (é)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49129/question-about-acute-accentuation-laccent-aigu-%c3%a9)

> On met un accent aigu lorsque la voyelle "e" est placée entre deux consonnes

Here the "e" is between "f" and "r"

Comment: That's barely possible since it is a post of my own.